# What effects to expect from 100+ generations living subterranean with constant low doses of radiation

Tags: post-apocalypse, radiation, underground, adaptability

Back story is that humans settled a foreign planet and the star began to die so humans went subterranean until the worst of the star death cycle passed (yes I know this process theoretically takes trillions of years, I'm working a fix for that) I can already account for how they survive, I just need to know what biological effects this would have over the course of 100-200 generations assuming that a portion of the radiation from the star death cycle penetrated the planet deep enough to reach the settlements.

Not looking for any bizarre mutations, just need to know what effects I need to account for/ find ways to prevent. Only change I'm actually looking for is a slightly boosted radiation resistance and I've already got the science to back that. Looking more for the subterranean effects and if radiation would make any of them worse eg. Change of bone density, mental instability, dietary struggles and nutrient retention, etc.

Setting- Subterranean structures are designed for long term use. Air circulates, large food crops act as air purifier, crops grown via uv lighting, Lights in common areas operate on a day night cycle, etc. Essentially they are built to replicate surface living as close as possible for as long as possible. Technology level degrades over the course of the bunkering as non essential tech gets scrapped for parts to keep essential systems operating.

Comment: Our own world is radiactive. Everything is radioactive, the water we drink, the air we breathe, the food we eat, the people among whom we live. We live in a world permeated by small doses of radiation, and we are in no way different from the Romans or the Gauls or the Dacians or whatever tribe of two thousand years ago.

Comment: Radiation is a very minor point in the question though Its relevance is based in it's higher than normal levels. Not enough to be blatantly adversely effecting the population, but enough that over the course of time it could play a part in exacerbating or nullifying the risk or inevitability of already present trends of adaptation due to the subterranean environment. The meat of what I'm asking is in the effects of 100-200 generations living exclusively underground and if radiation could/would cause/prevent/alter the progression of those adaptations, health effects, mental health changes, etc.

Comment: Where do you get this trillions of years from? Sol has an approximate 10 billion expected life span. The red giant phase is expect to balloon out to near Mars orbit. Underground living will not allow avoiding the thermal radiation. Unless you are dealing with a small red dwarf that is small enough to not have a red giant phase, which is not stated.

Comment: Full context is it's a M-class star gone red dwarf resulting in a tidal lock. I'm preventing the heat aspect with a tungsten particle cloud in the exosphere as a heat shield and accelerating the time line by injecting dicyanoacetylene into the star to hyper accelerate the burn rate (yes I realize that this also drastically increases the temperature and probably exceeds what a tungsten heat shield could block. I'm allowing for a little "because I said so" on that one) with that, time and temp are handled hence just asking about the effects of the multi generational subterranean life.

Comment: okay the Sun do gets brighter and bigger once it starts fusing helium but the deeper you dig the hotter it gets due to radioactive decay from the Earth's core. by that time we should already have a refrigerator that Indiana Jones used☢️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200 generations is nothing for any significant evolution to happen. For humans it would mean something around 3000-4000 years, and if you look back into our history we are not that different from the people who built the pyramids or started civilization in the fertile crescent.

Don't expect much changes, just maybe an increased incidence of cancer (depending on how intense is the background radiation) and plausibly an alteration of the circadian rhythms caused by the lack of exposure to sunlight, as it has been demonstrated by the experiments of prolonged human underground isolation.

Comment: You have forgotten the evolution of our immune system. It goes much faster and manages to cover the speed of the evolution of microbes and viruses. We are alive still, aren't we?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the star. Suppose you are on a planet orbiting a red dwarf. The planet is probably tidally locked to the star, so people will live in the twilight zone, making the most of the heat on one side and the cold on the other. The red dwarf will have large flares, so you would probably spend a lot of time underground or close to a tunnel in case a flare is sighted. You might want to keep your own atmosphere as the planet's air might get stripped by a really large flare - it would not go entirely but it mike make living difficult. That sort-of fits your description.

So, you might live underground. On the Earth, that might mean you get radioactivity leaking from the earth, but red dwasrf stars can have huge lifetimes, so you might in fact get a lot less radiation underground depending on how old the planet is.

It may not make a lot of difference. I used to work in a 'red area' where you had to wear protective clothing and radiation badges, and get your hands scanned when you left. But the background level was less than in Cornwall or Edinburgh.